# Алгоритм изменения звуков и музыки, чтобы не возникло проблем с авторством в гугл плэй

Tags: android, алгоритм, google-play

Делаю приложение, в нем будут использованы популярные звуки (например со стримов ютуберов или фрагмент популярной песни) можно ли как то изменить эти звуки, ( например прибавить дцб) чтобы не было проблем с авторством ?

Comment: Прибавить децибел это сделать погромче, а не изменить звук.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, прибавление децибел ничего не даст. Чтобы не возникло проблем с копирайтом, изменить мелодию надо **очень** сильно. По сути, сочинить новую или близко к тому. Даже просто похожая музыкальная фраза может послужить основанием для подачи комплейна на основании DMCA, после чего Гугл моментально ваше приложение заблокирует, как минимум до решения суда.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению на ютубе текущая ситуация такова, что даже с полностью авторским контентом невозможно полностью защититься от возможных атак.

Дело и в том, что автоматические алгоритмы гугла могут случайно ошибиться и в том, что множество недобросовестных контор рассылает автоматом по всем видео жалобы и в том, что многие ставят копирайт на то, что им не принадлежит (советские мультфильмы, звуки природы - почитайте, много нового узнаете)

На текущий момент не является хорошей защитой то, что вы используете короткие (до 30 секунд) фрагменты песен.

Что работает? Например, многие популярные музыкальные влоггеры используют транспонирование мелодии в другую тональность и собственное исполнение. На первый способ в автоматическом режиме я бы не рассчитывал, а второй вам не особо подойдёт.

Дешевле делать собственный контент или покупать права.